# Dequeue a collection to write to disk until no more items left in collection

Tags: c#, csv, asynchronous, collections, blockingcollection

So, I have a list of file shares.
I then need to obtain ALL folders in these file shares. This is all the "easy" stuff I have done.
Ultimately after some logic, I am adding an object into a collection.

All the while this is happening in the background using Async/Await and Tasks, I want to be able to have another thread/task spin up so it can keep going through the collection and write data to disk.

Now, for each folder, I obtain security information about that folder. There will be at LEAST 1 item. But for each item, I add this information into a collection (for each folder).

I want to write to disk in a background until there are no more folders to iterate through and the job is complete.

I was thinking of using a `BlockingCollection` however this code does smell and ultimately does not close the file because of the `while(true)` statement.

```
private static BlockingCollection<DirectorySecurityInformation> AllSecurityItemsToWrite = new BlockingCollection<DirectorySecurityInformation>();

if (sharesResults.Count > 0)
{
    WriteCSVHeader();

    // setup a background task which will dequeue items to write.
    var csvBGTask = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(FileName, true))
        {
            sw.AutoFlush = true;
            while (true)
            {
                var dsi = AllSecurityItemsToWrite.Take();
                await sw.WriteLineAsync("... blah blah blah...");
                await sw.FlushAsync();
            }
        }
    });
    allTasks.Add(csvBGTask);
}

foreach(var currentShare in AllShares)
{
   var dirs = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(currentShare .FullName, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
   foreach(var currentDir in dirs) { // Spin up a task in the BG and run to do some security analysis and add to the AllSecurityItemsToWrite collection }
}
```

This is at its simplest but core example.
Any ideas? I just want to keep adding on the background task and have another task just dequeue and write to disk until there are no more shares to go through (`shareResults`).

Answer (score 1):

Recommand to use [Channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel?view=net-6.0).

```
Channel<DirectorySecurityInformation> ch = 
    Channel.CreateUnbounded<DirectorySecurityInformation>();
```

Write

```
var w = ch.Writer;
foreach(var dsi in DSIs)
    w.TryWrite(dsi);
w.TryComplete();
```

Read

```
public async void ReadTask()
{
    var r = ch.Reader;
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(filename, true))
    {
        await foreach(var dsi in r.ReadAllAsync())
            sw.WriteLine(dsi);
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. This is a good suggestion but did not work for me when I have multiple BG tasks running concurrently. The ReadTask never seems to get invoked and when doing a TryWrite, it returns false.

Comment: @Ahmedilyas there are only two cases that the `TryWrite` might return `false`. If the channel was created as [bounded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel.createbounded) and it's currently full, or if the channel has been [completed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelwriter-1.complete).

Comment: Def not bounded. Hmm.

Comment: So you must have `Complete/TryComplete` called somewhere. A working example https://dotnetfiddle.net/kxsYk7

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> while (true)
> {
>     var dsi = AllSecurityItemsToWrite.Take();
>     //...
> }
> ```

Instead of using the [`Take`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1.take) method, it's generally more convenient to consume a `BlockingCollection<T>` with the [`GetConsumingEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1.getconsumingenumerable) method:

```
foreach (var dsi in AllSecurityItemsToWrite.GetConsumingEnumerable())
{
    //...
}
```

This way the loop will stop automatically when the [`CompleteAdding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1.completeadding) method is called, and the collection is empty.

But I agree with [shingo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72590738/11178549) that the `BlockingCollection<T>` is not the correct tool in this case, because your workers are running on an asynchronous context. A [`Channel<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel-1) should be preferable, because it can be consumed without blocking a thread.